# MongoDB Driver C#, Search by nested property using filter definition

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need help with building filter for MongoCollection of class A when I have filters for class B

```
    public class A
    {
        public string ExampleAProperty { get; set; }

        public B NestedB { get; set; }

        public ICollection<B> NestedBCollection { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public string ExampleBProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchClass
    {
        public async Task<ICollection<A>> SearchAsync(IMongoCollection<A> collection)
        {
            // this is just simple example of possible dozens predefined filters for B class.
            // see FilterProvider logic used now
            // var bFilter = Builders<B>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ExampleBProperty, "Example");

            // in need filter A where B meets provided filters 

            var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(
                Builders<A>.Filter.And( 
                    // predefined filters are easy to reuse with array of elements
                    Builders<A>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.NestedBCollection, FilterProvider.SearchValue("Oleh")),
                    
                    // but i did not found how to do this with single nested element 
                    Builders<A>.Filter.Eq(x => x.NestedB, FilterProvider.SearchValue("Oleh")) // how?
                )
            );
            return await cursor.ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    // statics is not good but just for working example :)
    public static class FilterProvider
    {
        public static FilterDefinition<B> SearchValue(string? value)
        {
            var builder = Builders<B>.Filter;

            // if value is null show all
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return builder.Empty;
            }

            // if value is "Oleh" search for "Amir"
            if (value == "Oleh")
            {
                value = "Amir";
            }

            // any other additional logic to compose proper filter
            // this could be search by serveral properties and so on
            // however just for example i will search by hashed value :)
            value = value.GetHashCode().ToString();

            return builder.Eq(x => x.ExampleBProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Please DON'T

1. use IMongoQueryable
2. propose to filter nested element by duplicate code (like x => x.NestedB.ExampleBProperty = "something")

UPDATED: example for Amir with explanation why p.2 is not than case and  why code will be is duplicated if you his approach :)
As you may see we have complex (but very simple in current example) filter of data in B class. If you will use your approach - logic of composing filter for B (specified in FilterProvider.SearchValue) will be duplicated.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My English is not perfect, however task clearly described in the C# code. I need to filter A collection by applying filter to nested B property (which is not array, with arrays we use ElemMatch)

Comment: Intent should never be interpreted from code.  That is backwards.  Intent should be derived from requirements, and code should match.  Too many times I have tried to fix a bug without requirement definitions only to find out the developer of the code had a misunderstanding and thus implemented the wrong thing.  As such, please state your intent so we may help.  If the task were clearly described in code you would have no reason to ask a question here.

Comment: There are no reason to post your abstract thoughts here as well, instead of advise how to reuse existing FilterDefinitions when entity is nested...

Comment: The reason for my comment is simple.  I cannot help you if I do not understand what you are seeking.  Help me help you.

Comment: If you are unwilling to provide details then I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: I provided especially for you additional example of the issue, if you still don't understand what am I seeking - I give up :)

Comment: I still don't get why my answer is not correct. `duplicate code`?? @OlehHochachko

Comment: damn someone was grumpy on Oct 19 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this:

```
public async Task<ICollection<A>> SearchAsync(IMongoCollection<A> collection, string search)
{
    var bFilter = Builders<B>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ExampleBProperty, search);

    var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(
                    Builders<A>.Filter.And(
                        Builders<A>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.NestedBCollection, bFilter),
                        Builders<A>.Filter.Eq(x => x.NestedB.ExampleBProperty, search)
                    )
    );
    return await cursor.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: as i said in starting message Eq(x => x.NestedB.ExampleBProperty, "search") is not what is I'm i looking for. when you use such approach you are duplicating logic of filtering nested properties.

Comment: updated example to explain where you duplicating the code.